# Compile .so in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries

Is there any way to compile a source code to .so instead of .dll in Windows and using Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <sarcasm>Would renaming the resulting file cut it?</sarcasm> What do you want, use shared object files in windows or cross-compile for *nix or something completely different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A .so library cannot be deployed on Windows and VS can't create one. But if what you want is to cross-compile for some platform (*NIX) which does support it, you can try using Cygwin.