# How can i run only one file without having influence on others

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.
I have 2 files cpp. I want to run the second but when i press Ctrl F5, the first one runs.
How can i run only one file without having influence on others.

Comment: C++ programs don't have the concept of "files". They simply run the `main` function.

Comment: Create a 3rd file with main, and call only the functions you want to run. Or create 2 projects each with one of the files in it.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: As the comment by user Botje detailed, C++ doesn't recognise files, only code. I realise I've said things like "main file" which are practically correct, but technically wrong.*

Whichever file contains the `main()` function will run as the main file, so if you only want the second file to run, put the main function in the second file. The other file will only have an effect on the program if it is referenced in some way, so check for any ways the first file is referenced by the second file at all (things like the second file including a header that is implemented in the first file).

I'm not sure why you want to do this at all, though. The above should work but if I were you, I would just either delete the first file if it's never being used, or delete the section of code that I never want to be run. You could just comment out all the code that you don't want to use if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has the notion of projects. Each project can contain at most one `main`. If you have two .cpp files, each with their own main, make two projecs.

In the solution window, you can choose the "Startup Project". This is the one that runs on F5. But you can also right-click on other projects to start those.

Comment: "at most one `main`", because library projects have zero. Windows DLL projects can have a `DllMain`, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comments by @JackBennett and @MSalters suggests,
The C++ projects should have **one main function** from where the execution would start.
But I have come across situations where I had to compile a library separately, *which I guess you are referring here*, so you can check [this post [Compile .so in Windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630109/compile-so-in-windows) for some help.

Again, C++ program, in VS should be viewed as project instead of files with proper file structure for clarity and re-usability. And thus programmer should ensure one entry point (i.e. main function) and include relative header files and libraries being used appropriately.